Can I prevent "^Z" from being printed when I handle SIGTSTP (Ctrl-Z) in my program?
In Linux I need to print the terminal program status when the user presses some keyboard hotkey.
Since Ctrl+T isn't available on Linux (it is only available on BSDs), I decided to use Ctrl+Z instead.
I handle the SIGTSTP signal in my program, and it works fine.
One side-effect is that the characters ^Z appear when the user presses Ctrl+Z.
Can the ^Z printout be eliminated?

As a concrete example, consider the following program:
#!/usr/bin/env python
import signal, sys, time

def deliberately_no_stop(*args):
  print('Status printout', file=sys.stderr)

signal.signal(signal.SIGTSTP, deliberately_no_stop)
time.sleep(5)

When run from an interactive console, and pressing Ctrl+Z twice, the actual content printed to the terminal is:
^ZStatus printout
^ZStatus printout

...whereas I want it to be:
Status printout
Status printout

How can I get this effect?

It's not the shell doing the printing at all: it happens even with no shell running. More likely this is a stty-configurable terminal setting.

...confirmed that it is. Probably you can configure it via https://docs.python.org/3/library/termios.html#module-termios, but that would be a Python question rather than a shell question.

This is the terminal's local echo support -- the same thing that prints characters the user is typing back for them to review.
You can disable translation of control characters into two-character sequences like ^Z with stty -echoctl, or outright prevent them from being printed in any form (also suppressing other local echo) with stty -echo.
To do either of those changes from Python, one could use functions like the following:
import termios

def disable_terminal_flags(flags_to_disable: int) -> int:
    try:
        with open('/dev/tty', 'r+') as tty_file:
            tty_fd = tty_file.fileno()
            settings = termios.tcgetattr(tty_fd)
            disabled_flags = flags_to_disable & settings[3]
            settings[3] &= ~ flags_to_disable
            termios.tcsetattr(tty_fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, settings)
            return flags_to_disable
    except OSError:
        return 0

def enable_terminal_flags(flags_to_enable: int) -> int:
    try:
        with open('/dev/tty', 'r+') as tty_file:
            tty_fd = tty_file.fileno()
            settings = termios.tcgetattr(tty_fd)
            toggled_flags = flags_to_enable & ~settings[3]
            settings[3] |= flags_to_enable
            termios.tcsetattr(tty_fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, settings)
            return toggled_flags
    except OSError:
        return 0

...used as:
import signal, sys, termios, time

def deliberately_no_stop(*args):
  print('Status printout', file=sys.stderr)

original_echo_state = disable_terminal_flags(termios.ECHOCTL | termios.ECHO)
try:
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTSTP, deliberately_no_stop)
    time.sleep(5)
finally:
    enable_terminal_flags(original_echo_state)

Again, note that we're disabling all local echo -- if you need to collect user input, you'll want to either have your code explicitly echo what the user is typing back to them ("remote echo"), or temporarily reenable local echo only for the duration of the prompting operation.

You also want to change it back on process exit.

This works, thanks! Konsole (the KDE5 terminal) has a bug that it prints some white box instead of ^Z now. And XFCE4 terminal also has a bug and it prints the � character.

@JenniferM., ...you might consider disabling local echo altogether (stty -echo); that way control characters don't try to print even as their literal ASCII values.

As discussed in https://gitlab.xfce.org/apps/xfce4-terminal/-/issues/341 and the linked VTE issue, it seems that printing a replacement character (�, ␦, ▒ or alike) when echo is on but echoctl is off, and ^Z is pressed, is the correct behavior of a terminal emulator. XFCE4 Terminal and Konsole do what the standards say to do, unlike those terminals that don't print anything here.

@egmont, yes -- I believe the answer already indicates as much.

This does not directly answer your question, but is something that I find crucial to mention.
I would strongly advise you against doing anything like this from a signal handler.
Signal handlers are hard to write correctly, they are extremely easy to get wrong. There are two main issues.
One is that you're not guaranteed to see a consistent view of the world. Let's say your app maintains two counters, one for the number of tasks completed, and one for the number of remaining tasks to complete. At any moment they add up to some constant. Well, except for that brief moment when your business logic increments the former and decrements the latter. If you happen to press ^Z just between these two steps, your report would be incorrect. With more complex data structures (e.g. linked list) you might even encounter an intermittent state that is so inconsistent with itself that you follow a NULL or invalid pointer causing a crash, or such. The only way to prevent against this is to block the delivery of the related signal for any such period of time when the values you want to report are intermittently inconsistent, and unblock the signal when they're back to being consistent with each other. I don't think anyone ever wants to implement this behavior and guarantee to maintain this behavior across future refactorings potentially done by other developers, let alone figuring out how to cover these cases with unittests. Also, blocking or unblocking a signal involves a system call which might be to slow for you (in the ballpark of 1µs each).
The other is: you're pretty limited in the number of things you can do. For example, you cannot use high-level stdio methods (like printf()) in a signal handler, they can lock up your application. So can malloc(). See the signal-safety manual page for a list of methods you're allowed to use. I'm sure you wouldn't like to limit yourself to those. Also, if your app produces any other output otherwise, in non-atomic steps, the signal handler can interrupt them and result in garbage appearing on the screen.
For these two reasons, it is extremely hard to correctly, fully reliably print the report from any signal handler. An incorrect implementation would work the vast majority of the time, but you can never know when, 1 out of 1000 or 10000 or even more occasions, your program will crash, lock up, or just report incorrect data that causes problems in turn. And at that point it'll be very hard to reproduce, locate and fix the bug.
An often seen pattern for handling signals is that you simply flip a volatile bool variable, and then the app's idle point (typically a pselect()/ppoll() atomically unblocking the signal's delivery, or in the main loop as provided by a higher level library) checks for this boolean. That is, the actual printing of your status would not happen from signal handling context. Alternatively, you can block signal delivery for most of the program's duration, and only momentarily unblock it at certain points in the code (preferably at just 1 pont) that you know have a consistent state, is okay to be interrupted, and is visited frequently by the code.
For either of these cases, you can replace that signal by just checking the raw input on your stdin, i.e. handle keypresses that don't even require the Ctrl modifier key. Signals no longer help you at all, they just limit you because there are very of them you can use. And, by the way, they also complicate your life because of that echoed back character that bothers you.
Using signals for this is extremely rarely seen, the only example occurring to me right now is dd printing a status report. The main reason there is to be able to send this signal externally, e.g. from another terminal window. I don't think you need this. If you really do, you might check how dd does it, I haven't, but I bet they got it right and I bet it's way more complicated than what you'd expect and what you'd be happy duplicating in your code.
Forget signals. Just disable echoing, and check stdin for input bytes/letters that you handle.

Update, further clarification:
So, there are applications that revolve around a "main loop" or "main event loop". There is a "resting point" where the command sits idle if otherwise nothing happens (no external condition triggers any work to be done), and if there is some event to handle then it's handled in a relatively short amount of time. For these apps, letting that main loop handle the signals is a well-known practice. This update is not about these.
There's another kind of applications: ones that have a fixed set of things to do locally, and do them as fast as they can. These include cp or dd to copy a file; gcc, thisformat2thatformat and similar apps that read an input file, do some computation, and then produce an output file; etc. Assuming that your utility falls in this category:
If you want to notice a certain keypress, you can use a non-blocking read() or a select() or similar method to check if there's input available. There's a problem with this method, though. If you check too rarely then the report might be delayed, but if you check way too frequently then it might be expensive (each such syscall taking up roughly 1µs). It might not be easy to find a repetition interval between let's say 100µs (already causes a 1% performance loss) and 50000µs (3 UI frames at 60Hz which is already a noticeable delay), no matter what your program does, what computer it runs on, what the load of that system is.
Here is where watching for a signal might come handy. Actually handling it (printing the report) from the handler is a no-go due to all the aforementioned complications. But it could flip a global volatile bool, and checking for that variable plenty of times (e.g. in your innermost loops) is essentially free.
However, you're still limited by the low number of available signals and hotkeys, you can't have many keys each producing a different status report, or such.
If you don't want signals, on Linux (not sure about BSD) I'd recommend to write a tiny inline helper function that queries the monotonic clock, compares the timestamp with the one of the latest such query (which you track in a global variable), and only if 1/60 or so seconds have elapsed then actually look at the file descriptor. The trick is that, at least on Linux, clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC) and friends are implemented via some VDSO hack; they are nowhere near as expensive as regular syscalls (~1µs), they are super-duper cheap, their cost is negligible. This way you could call this helper method frequently from the innermost loops of your business logic, and still only look at the input file descriptor at a reasonable frequency that does not impact performance. So, the advantage of signals, namely the cheapness, is also available without signals. (Someone just needs to confirm whether clock_gettime() is this super fast on BSD and others, too.)

I'm leaving it to you figure out how to translate my C into your Python.

Some of the concerns about signal safety are handled by the Python interpreter -- the same global lock prevents code triggered by signals from running concurrently with other operations changing interpreter state as prevents said state from being clobbered by code in other threads. There's room for higher-level state management problems, but those have the same solutions that would apply with any other kind of asynchronous notifications -- set a flag to dump state next time your regular event loop executes, etc.

(Personally, I spent enough time in the Clojure world to have a deep appreciation of having one's state managed by a reference to an immutable structure that gets replaced on changes -- granted, doing that efficiently calls for specialist structures, such as those implemented in the Python world via https://pypi.org/project/pyrsistent/)
